# Change unicode characters in UTF-8 from symbol to numeric code

Tags: ruby, unicode, nokogiri, iconv

I'm using Ruby (and Nokogiri in case that is helpful) to encode some documents. I want to change actual unicode characters (like `“`) to html entities (like `&#8220;`). How do I do this? I know I can do a single character with something like

```
s = '“'    
puts "&##{.unpack('U').first};"   # gives &#8220;
```

but is there a way to do this properly using iconv or nokogiri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with this method, which takes a quite brute-force approach which is surely (hopefully?) replaced by a compiled library solution? It works though:

```
def clean(text)
  # Convert html chars to entities.
  text = text.gsub(/[^\u{20}-\u{7E}]/){|char| "&##{char.unpack('U')[0]};"}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the [HTMLEntities gem](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/doc/). For it's decimal encoding it does about the same as your code (unpack).

Answer (score 1):

It may not be proper but nokogiri does this (libxml2 I think actually) when it doesn't understand the encoding:

```
Nokogiri::HTML(html,nil,'klingon')
```